# What can be used to remove make-up?

Tags: personal-care, makeup

What else can be used (that's not harsh on skin) to remove make-up besides liquid make-up remover?

**Make-up such as:**

- Eyeliner
- Mascara
- Eye Shadow
- Blush
- Foundation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use coconut oil. I am allergic to ingredients that are in most 
skin creams on the market.  Coconut oil is a natural product and
is good for the skin.

Answer (score 7):

Many types of make-up are oil-based, so just use mineral oil (or even vegetable oil) to remove it. Put the oil on cotton, facial tissue or face towels. (Just be careful to wash a cloth immediately, as oily rags are a fire hazard.)

You could use fancy prepared oil-based skin cleansers, but vegetable oil is kinder to the skin. Avoid harsh cleaners.

Answer (score 3):

Baby Oil works very very well and is very safe to use without questioning its application.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how sensitive you are - most eye make up removers are oil based, and they make my eyes swell up. I just use facial wipes, the ones sold for general make up remover, and clean eye make up off with those too, works fine. I always choose Johnson's Dry Skin (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Johnsons-Face-Makeup-Moisturising-Wipes/dp/B00G3JNU8Q) ones because some of the other makes (L'Oreal, Olay) cause a reaction. Not sure if you can get them where you are, otherwise, Simple facial wipes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use organic products  You can use olive oil, vinegar with water, instead of the harsh chemical ones on your skin. You can even make your own makeup remover just refer to the video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bMSKRpiUZWE 
You can easily find the items on your household.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. Please don't just add links, as links tend to die in due time. Please do describe what the link/video describes, and list the items used.